# Group by time near to time

Tags: sql, oracle

Aloha everyone, I've been searching along all questions about group by time in stackoveflow and no one ask what I need. Here is my doubt.
I have this table:

[image]

I have many request (ID_SOL) from the same person (ID_PERSONA). Each one made at distinct time. I want to group them by the time in a 15 minutes interval.

For example: First row have this time 7:23:35 AM, and this would be group with all request until 7:38:35 AM. And then the next request after that have 7:39:36 AM should start a new group with time interval 7:39:36 AM - 7:54:36 AM.

In image 2 you can see my expected result:

[image]

I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    ID_CREACION, 
    ID_PERSONA,
    ID_MOTIVO,
    ID_FEC_CREACION, 
    ID_FEC_CREACION+(1/1440*15) ID_FEC_MAX,
    ID_NUM_SOL,
    ID_SOL,
    FIRST_VALUE(ID_SOL) OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CREACION,ID_PERSONA
            ORDER BY ID_FEC_CREACION RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '15' MINUTE PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) ID_SOL_P,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID_CREACION, ID_CLIENTE, ID_FEC_CREACION, ID_FEC_CREACION+(1/1440*15) ORDER BY ID_FEC_CREACION) ID_FILA
FROM 
    VITAR_AGUS_SOL
```

But I'm getting this:

[image]

I'm not being able to start a new group after finish the first one. What can I do in SQL? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I might misinterpret your question, but couldn't it be done by just filtering over ID_FEC_CREATION? I mean, you're checking row neighbours, because data is date-sensitive, but you can just filter on that

Comment: It's not possible just filtering over FEC_CREACION, I mean you can get first group well done, but next one will be wrong because it will overlap the first one. I need the group don't overlap with the previous one.

Comment: You told 2nd group to 7:49:36, but on image 2 i can't see this?

Comment: @hekko I made a mistake, I wrote intervals of 10 minutes but they are of 15 minutes. So first group is from FEC_CREACION of first row: 7:23:35 AM to 7:38:35 AM and second group is from FEC_CREACION of the first row do not belong to first group, it is 7:39:36 AM to 7:54:36 AM.

Answer (score 0):

A little confused), but maybe useful:

```
select ID_CREACION, ID_PERSONA, ID_FEC_CREACION, ID_SOL, ID_SOL_P 
from VITAR_AGUS_SOL
model dimension by ( 
    ID_CREACION, 
    ID_PERSONA, 
    row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY ID_CREACION, ID_PERSONA 
                        ORDER BY ID_FEC_CREACION ) ord )
MEASURES ( ID_FEC_CREACION, ID_SOL, 0 min_dt, 0 ID_SOL_P )
rules(
    min_dt[ ID_CREACION, ID_PERSONA, ord > 0 ] order by ID_CREACION, ID_PERSONA, ord =
        case 
            when ID_FEC_CREACION[ cv( ID_CREACION ), cv( ID_PERSONA ), cv( ord ) ] 
                    - ID_FEC_CREACION[ cv( ID_CREACION ), cv( ID_PERSONA ), 
                    min_dt[ cv( ID_CREACION ), cv( ID_PERSONA ), cv( ord ) - 1 ] ] < 15/1440 
                then min_dt[ cv( ID_CREACION ), cv( ID_PERSONA ), cv( ord ) - 1 ] 
            else cv( ord ) 
        end,
    ID_SOL_P[ ID_CREACION, ID_PERSONA, ord ] = ID_SOL[ cv( ID_CREACION ), 
                    cv( ID_PERSONA ), 
                    min_dt[ cv( ID_CREACION ), 
                    cv( ID_PERSONA ), cv( ord ) ] ]
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it, looks like good. Do you know if I can use model dimension clause in a ctas file?